# Razorpages: Setting Custom font in CSS fails

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to set my custom font. I donwloaded it into wwwroot / fonts / bebaseNeue-regular.ttf

Now I am trying:

```
@@font-face {
    font-family: bebas_neue;
    src: url('~/fonts/BebaseNeue-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
}


.majorHeadline{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: bebas_neue;
}
```

Inside .

But it tells me that src is not known and that the double @ sign is incorrect.

What is the issue here?

Comment: The url has an extra `"` in it. And in a css file you don't need a double `@`, only if you write it on a razor page itself.

Comment: @VDWWD oh, i didnt see the extra " - you were right. although i still get both errors. And i am inside a cshtml file inside the style tags. This still doenst seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~/ is an artificial path resolution character only ASP.NET, it can't be used in CSS path. Instead use relative or absolute URL path without the ~

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bebas_neue;
    src: url('/fonts/BebaseNeue-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```